# Open existing database with SQLAlchemy declarative

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have generated all tables using SQLAlchemy declarative methodology, eg each table class extending a Base class as below:

```
class Base(object):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return str(cls.__name__)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable = False)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

I want to be able to open a database I have saved - as I have generated all the tables already I don't want to use reflection with declarative or auto table generation. The only documentation I could find on this was here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/10/sqlalchemy-connecting-to-pre-existing-databases/ - specifically the 'Defining Your Databases Explicitly' section using declarative style where a init method is defined:

```
def __init__(self, id, url, title, rev_host, visit_count,
             hidden, typed, favicon_id, frecency, last_visit_date):
    self.id = id
    #etc
```

and where one gets a session using this method:

```
def loadSession():
    metadata = Base.metadata
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    return session
```

Is this the best approach - create an **init** method for each table class with each database field defined?

Then I am not sure how I would integrate getting sessions, with my existing DBManager class were I create a new database and get a session using:

```
host= db_path + db_name
def init_db(self):
    #import table classes here
    self.engine = create_engine(self.host, echo=False)
    self.base = Base()
    self.base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)    

def getSession(self):
    if self.ready():
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        session = Session()
        return session
    else:
        return None
```

eg I could have some sort of global flag - if DB is existing get session using methodology a, if new DB get session using methodology b? Any guidelines on best practices?